numpy polynomial roots incorrect compared to Matlab?
I would like to figure out the roots of the polynomial x^2 - 800x + 160000, which has a multiple root of 400.
In Matlab, if I type roots([1 -800 160000), I correctly get ans = 400.0000, 400.0000 whereas numpy np.roots([1, -800, 160000]) gives me array([400.+2.69940682e-06j, 400.-2.69940682e-06j]).
Why does numpy show some sort of floating point precision issue when matlab does not? Do they not both use an algorithm based on the companion matrix? How can I reliably determine, in Python, that the "actual" roots are 400, as Matlab seems to be doing?
Edit: This is a "toy" example that I am facing in a larger, more complex algorithm that is not necessarily faced with only real roots and multiple roots i.e. I do not actually know in advance, in my more complicated case, that the root is multiple and real.

If you know the roots are real, then just do answer = answer.real.  The imprecision there is all on the complex side.

@TimRoberts this is a toy example that I am facing in a much more complex algorithm - I do not know the roots are real in advanced

Are you able to use a 64-bit computer (or 64-bit python?) That has enough precision for your example, although the issue you're running into is an inherent problem with floating point numbers, so you'll probably find an example in one of your more complex polynomials where even 64-bit floats won't have enough precision.

This boils down to which algorithm is used in np.roots. The short answer is in general, you should not be relying on the exact equality when comparing floating point numbers. Always expecting small errors in floating point arithmetic.

What version of numpy do you use? I am getting [400., 400.] in  1.24.2

I can't reproduce neither the error.  Besides, 1 case would not be enough to prove a real difference. I mean, it is numerical error, and numerical error is a bit random. On a single case, you could say that maybe matlab was just lucky. But, anyway, I am getting [400, 400], like Yuri. With numpy 1.26.4

@YuriGinsburg I am on version 1.26.4

@chrslg Are you sure? I am on the same version an am definitely getting a small imaginary part. Also, my question is not about this specific instance, but rather what techniques I can implement to confirm that, confidently, the roots are only real

Yes, I am (I just cut and pasted version number. And I don't use environments on this computer, so there is only one numpy version). Anyway, I don't know how matlab (or my numpy, or Yuri's numpy) does to have a pure real solution. But I am pretty sure it is a display strategy: under a given threshold, imaginary part is considered 0. Because there is always some numerical. Maybe for the specific case of degree 2 polynomials there is a specific criteria (if coefficients are reals, not just complex with 0 imaginary, but of float64 type for example, and if b²≥4ac, then results are pure reals)

In your case, since Δ is 0, that might be where a numerical error can occur randomly. If 800**2-160000*4 gives a slightly negative number because of numerical error... But again, hard to tell with a single example (I know, your question is not about specific example, as you said several times. But you gave only one and no code). For example, does this occurs only with degree-2 polynomial with a unique solution (in which case, numerical error occurring when computing Δ=b²-4ac is the source of random small imaginary part)

I run this slightly ugly test:
max([
    np.abs(
        (np.roots(
            [1, -2 * i, i ** 2]
        ) / i - 1)
    ).max() 
    for i in range(1, 1000000, 10)
])

and got result 1.91e-08
You can do the same for your version of numpy and estimate the precision of answers, and if a ratio of the imaginary part to the real is less than it you can just drop it.
Also, interesting fact from tests: if roots are different, errors are very little, ~1e-16 or even 0, but when roots are the same, errors are almost never zero and have magnitude of 1e-8~1e-9.

Thank you very much - I ended up using this approach for my particular problem to put a very conservative estimate of 1e-6 on the ratio of the imaginary to real parts, and in my case that was all I needed. Cheers!

Numerical precision is somewhat limited, especially when many operations are involved, such as root calculation, division and so on. In your example, the roots can be calculated using different approaches, which in turn give slightly different results. To illustrate this, I use the following example, where I not only change the floating-point precision, but also use two different numpy algorithms for the same task.
Important Also note that sometimes floats are not printed with the full precision of decimals and are therefore rounded beforehand, e.g. your Matlab example has 4 decimals.
Numpy provides information about the dtype such as decimal precision with np.finfo and you can setup the decimals used for prints with np.set_printoptions(precision=15) or combine both as showed in my example.
import numpy as np
print(f'numpy version: {np.__version__}\n')

def print_roots(roots):
    print(f'    roots (round to 5 decimals): {np.round(roots, 5)}')
    print(f'    roots (round to 6 decimals): {np.round(roots, 6)}')
    print(f'    roots (full decimals)      : {roots}')
    print(f'    roots (full decimals real) : {roots.real}')
    print(f'    roots (full decimals imag) : {roots.imag}')
    print()
    

coefficients = np.array([1, -800, 160000])
for i in [np.float32, np.float64]:
    print(f'type: {i}')
    print(f'{np.finfo(i)}')
    
    np.set_printoptions(precision=np.finfo(i).precision)
    poly = np.polynomial.Polynomial(coefficients.astype(i)[::-1])
    print(f'  np.polynomial.Polynomial: f(x) = {poly}')
    print_roots(poly.roots())

    print('  np.roots:')
    print_roots(np.roots(coefficients.astype(i)))

My output
numpy version: 1.26.4

type: <class 'numpy.float32'>
Machine parameters for float32
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =   6   resolution = 1.0000000e-06
machep =    -23   eps =        1.1920929e-07
negep =     -24   epsneg =     5.9604645e-08
minexp =   -126   tiny =       1.1754944e-38
maxexp =    128   max =        3.4028235e+38
nexp =        8   min =        -max
smallest_normal = 1.1754944e-38   smallest_subnormal = 1.4012985e-45
---------------------------------------------------------------

  np.polynomial.Polynomial: f(x) = 160000.0 - 800.0·x + 1.0·x²
    roots (round to 5 decimals): [400. 400.]
    roots (round to 6 decimals): [400. 400.]
    roots (full decimals)      : [400. 400.]
    roots (full decimals real) : [400. 400.]
    roots (full decimals imag) : [0. 0.]

  np.roots:
    roots (round to 5 decimals): [400. 400.]
    roots (round to 6 decimals): [400. 400.]
    roots (full decimals)      : [400. 400.]
    roots (full decimals real) : [400. 400.]
    roots (full decimals imag) : [0. 0.]

type: <class 'numpy.float64'>
Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
smallest_normal = 2.2250738585072014e-308   smallest_subnormal = 4.9406564584124654e-324
---------------------------------------------------------------

  np.polynomial.Polynomial: f(x) = 160000.0 - 800.0·x + 1.0·x²
    roots (round to 5 decimals): [400. 400.]
    roots (round to 6 decimals): [399.999995 400.000005]
    roots (full decimals)      : [399.99999540067506 400.00000459932517]
    roots (full decimals real) : [399.99999540067506 400.00000459932517]
    roots (full decimals imag) : [0. 0.]

  np.roots:
    roots (round to 5 decimals): [400. 400.]
    roots (round to 6 decimals): [400.000002 399.999998]
    roots (full decimals)      : [400.00000241746056 399.99999758253955]
    roots (full decimals real) : [400.00000241746056 399.99999758253955]
    roots (full decimals imag) : [0. 0.]

